# Replace style of an html element jquery

Tags: jquery, replace, styles

In the below html element,

```
<canvas style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1017.5px; height: 226.5px;" ></canvas>
```

I need to replace only the width and height in the style attribute with another values. How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Thanks...

Comment: `$('canvas').width(newWidthValue).height(newHeightValue)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<canvas style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1017.5px; height: 226.5px;" ></canvas>
```

To change `width` and `height`

do

```
$('canvas').width(w).height(h);
```

These `w` and `h` are new values and are supposed to be in `px`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this too with `css()` parameter

```js
newWidth = 400;
newHeight= 400;
$("canvas").css({width:newWidth, height:newHeight})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; background: #000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1017.5px; height: 226.5px;" ></canvas>
```